# Mongodb command execution using Batch script

Tags: mongodb, batch-file, command-line, automation

I am using this batch script:

```
mongo.exe mydb < D:\TFX\Delta\script.txt
```

in which script.txt contains mongodb commands to execute but on running the batch file it only runs the command written in single line and throwing error for commands written in multiple lines so,
I need solution to run commands written in multiple lines.

Comment: Try `mongo.exe mydb D:\TFX\Delta\script.txt` - however the script must have extension `.js` instead of `.txt`

Comment: thank you, will try that and revert back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try for this script:

```
mongo.exe mydb < D:\TFX\Delta\script.js
```

but some times it works with .txt extension too, it was working fine for me earlier.